# How to determine number of pixels between view and top of screen

Tags: android

I am using an animation to slide a view to the top of the screen. The problem in that the translation argument can be stated only in terms of pixels.

```
view.animate().translationY(
    // argument must be stated in pixels
);
```

How can I return the number of pixels spanning the space between the view and the top of the screen so that I may pass this number as an arugment.

Please note that I would like the view to fit underneath the status bar at the end of the animation, and that the view should not intersect the status bar.

Also, please note that the view I am trying to animate is nested within an absolute layout, if that makes a difference

```
<AbsoluteLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <!-- The view I am an animating -->
    <View
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:layout_y="300dp"/>

</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- *Suggestion 1*:

You can use [`View.getLocationOnScreen()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getLocationOnScreen%28int%5B%5D%29) or [`View.getLocationInWindow()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getLocationInWindow%28int%5B%5D%2) to get coordinates of your view in its screen/window (x,y).

Make sure to call those methods **after** view's size and position are calculated, otherwise they will return 0.

- *Suggestion 2*:

In your case (the view's parent is the root layout), you can use [`View.getTop()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getTop()), it will return the top position of the view relative to its parent.

Comment: Thanks. How do I declare the location object to pass to the methods in the first suggestion? Something like this? `Location location = (Location) findViewById(R.id.view);`

Comment: You're welcome, declare your view in `onCreate()` method and before using the 1st suggestion use `ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener()` to be sure that your view was positioned.